# Adding NULL in database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mapping, hibernate-onetomany

I am new to hibernate.

I have two classes UserDetails and Address.The relation between these two is One-To-Many.The details are as follows(Skiping getter and setters)
UserDetails.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserDetails")
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "UserName")
    private String userName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "address")
    private Collection<Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>();
}
```

Address.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
}
```

App.java

```
UserDetails ud=new UserDetails();
ud.setUserName("User 1");

Address ad1=new Address();
ad1.setCity("Mumbai");

Address ad2=new Address();
ad1.setCity("Pune");

ud.getAddress().add(ad1);
ud.getAddress().add(ad2);

Session session=factory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(ud);
session.save(ad1);
session.save(ad2);


session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

In hibernate.cfg.xml property name="hbm2ddl.auto" is set to update
After Running above code the entry in database is

UserDetails Table

```
userId       UserName     Address
1            User 1       NULL
```

Address Table

```
Id      City    Address
1       Pune    1
2       NULL    1
```

My Question is why hibernate is inserting in UserDetails Address=NULL and City=NULL in address table instead of creating new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Address ad2=new Address();
ad1.setCity("Pune");
```

You are  setting the city `pune` to `address1`,instead of `address2` try changing it as

```
 Address ad2=new Address();
    ad2.setCity("Pune");
```

**UPDATE**

Your user table adrees column is null because there is no mapped field in your pojo for address anyways your way of  database schema design is wrong implementing  onetomany relationship. Please check here [One to Many Hibernate](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) for proper way

Comment: Thanks got the mistake but its still showing NULL in UserDetails table for Address column..

Comment: @Niks Your database schema is not properly designed to implement onetomany relation please check the update

Comment: @Niks welcome :) if it helps you can choose as accepted that will help to others to find out the correct one

Answer (score 0):

**1st**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "userId")
private int userId;
```

UserDetails Table

Id UserName Address 1 User 1 NULL

Both conflicts column name of identity column differ, should be userId not id. Either correct in java file or in database.

**2nd**

```
Address ad2=new Address();
ad1.setCity("Pune");
```

this will set the city of ad1 not ad2. But this will not affect till there is a null check on the city column.

Comment: Thanks got the mistake but its still showing NULL in UserDetails table for Address column.For "1st" i had column name as userId in database so thats not the problem.